# Prove that $\theta \cdot (x,y)=(x\cos(\theta),x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta) )$ is an group action.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ the additive group of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{X}=\mathbb{R}^2$

Prove that

$$\theta \cdot (x,y)=(x\cos(\theta),x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta) ) $$

Define a group action of $G$ in $\mathbb{X}$

**My attempt:**

By definition $\theta:G\times \mathbb{X}:\rightarrow\mathbb{X}$ define a group action if

We know that $0$ is the zero element of $G$, then:

$0\cdot (x,y) = (x\cos 0,x\sin 0+y\cos 0) = (x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$

Now, we need to prove that $(\theta + \beta)\cdot(x,y)=\theta+(\beta\cdot(x,y))$ here i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the last thing you need to prove is that the way the group acts on things is consistent with the way elements in the groups are combined. So, that means "Apply $\beta$ to a point, and then applying $\theta$, is the same as [adding/multiplying] $theta$ and $\beta$, and then applying the result."

For example, matrices act of vectors. If you happen to have a collection of matrices that form a group *under matrix multiplication*, then yes, it's a group action, because $(AB)\mathbf{x}=A(B\mathbf{x})$ for any vector $\mathbf x$ and matrices $A$ and $B$. If your collection of matrices is a group under *matrix addition* though, then the group doesn't act on vectors as a group action: $(A+B)\mathbf x$ is not equal to $A(B\mathbf{x})$.

For your example, what you need to prove is that

$$\theta\cdot(\beta\cdot(x,y))=(\theta+\beta)\cdot(x,y)$$.

The simplest way is to expand the left hand side and the right hand side, and try to show they're equal. The left hand side is:

$$\theta\cdot(\beta\cdot(x,y)) = \theta\cdot(x\cos\beta, x\sin\beta+y\cos\beta)$$
which in turn is
$$\left((x\cos\beta)\cos\theta, (x\cos\beta)\sin\theta+(x\sin\beta+y\cos\beta)\cos\theta\right)$$

The right hand side is
$$(\theta+\beta)\cdot(x,y) = \theta\cdot(x\cos(\theta+\beta), x\sin(\theta+\beta)+y\cos(\theta+\beta))$$

To prove these are equal, you'd then use a bunch of trig to simplify things. Unfortunately, it will turn out they are not equal, and therefore this map from $G\times{\mathbb X}$ to $\mathbb X$ is not a group action.

Are you sure you typed the question correctly? Perhaps you meant

$$\theta\cdot(x,y)=(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta, x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)$$ instead?

Comment: Thanks @Michael Hartley yes, i made a mistake but know i understand how to proceed with the exercise. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your argument failed to be consistent at the end of your approach. you wrote $$(\theta+\beta)\cdot (x,y)=\theta+\beta\cdot(x,y) $$ which is wrong as $\beta\cdot (x,y)$ is an element of $X=R^2$ so $\theta$ will act as an action on $\beta\cdot(x,y)$.Therefore a natural symbol will be $\theta\cdot(\beta\cdot(x,y))$ on the right hand side.

So we are to show that $$(\theta+\beta)\cdot(x,y)=\theta\cdot(\beta\cdot(x,y)). $$Now,$(\theta+\beta)\cdot(x,y)=(x\cos(\theta+\beta),x\sin(\theta+\beta)+y\cos(\theta+\beta))$ and $\theta\cdot(\beta\cdot(x,y))=(x\cos\beta\cos\alpha,x\sin(\alpha+\beta)+y\cos\beta\cos\alpha)$ which may not be same all the time. So the proposed function may not be a group action. thank you.